# How to skip input control screen in Jasperserver (Using Hyperlink from Drill report)

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver, drilldown

Ok so I created a Drill down Report (lets call it `DrillONE`) which uses a hyperlink to drill down to a other report (lets call it `DrillTWO`)

the drill down report `(DrillTWO)` doesn't have Input controls because it gets all its info from the report that is calling it (DrillONE)

So the hyperlink to `DrillTWO` looks something like this

```
"./flow.html?_flowId=viewReportFlow&reportUnit=
 %2FNWU%2FStudentInformation%2FAcademicProgramDevelopment%2FAPQIBI005drill
 &startDate=" + new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format($P{startDate})"
```

Now my problem comes when Going back from `DrillTWO` to `DrillONE` (Without having to enter the input controles again and clicking RUN)

What happens is When I click the hyperlink back to `DrillONE` it sends the parameters and everything along fine, but it loads the input control screen and then the user has to run the report

I want it to go directly to `DrillONE` and run it, (Skip the input controle screen)

Answer (score 0):

Is DrillONE set to always prompt for input controls? Turn this off.

Comment: If I turn this off then The report always, Automatically runs
So this will solve my problem from gong from DrillTWO to DrillONE

But now creates a new problem because when DrillONE is run for the 1st time the Input controls don't come up

Comment: Do you mean the input controls are not visible?

Comment: Yes I want the input controles to be visible when DrillONE is Run, but not to show when it is Run from DrillTWO

Comment: You can copy the same report in two places and just change the prompt settings for input controls.

Comment: That is Very redundant, I will have two exact same reports with just one property differing, that's not the way to code